# Django Query / MySQL Database Optimization

Tags: mysql, django

This is kind of a two-fold question -- I'm pretty new to Django. My app uses Django to interface with a MySQL database and servicing data to a ReactJS frontend. I'm trying to make a query that will grab the latest entry (by time) off of a certain column value. For example:

```
class Cake(models.Model):
    bakery = models.CharField(Bakery)
    baked_at = models.DateTimeField()
    baker = models.ForeignKey(Baker)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(Buyer)
```

If I wanted to find **all** the latest cakes per given bakery name in one QuerySet, what would be a good query to run? Currently I have something like:

```
subquery = Cake.objects.filter(bakery=OuterRef('bakery')).order_by('-baked_at')
latest_cakes = Cake.objects.filter(baked_at=Subquery(subquery.values('baked_at')[:1]))
```

My second question is about database/serialization optimization. Say even if I'm just serializing all the cakes or just the latest_cakes, how should I optimize if I'm dealing with up to 10,000+ entries?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the result must be one record (assuming only one cake baked at one `baked_at` datetime):

```
latest_cake = Cake.objects.filter(baker=OuterRef('bakery')).order_by('-baked_at').first()
```

Assuming there are multiple cakes baked in a same datetime, then yes you need to get the datetime first (your code missed to re-filter the bakery in the second queryset, otherwise it's almost identical):

```
baked_at = Cake.objects.filter(bakery=OuterRef('bakery')).order_by('-baked_at').first().values('baked_at')
latest_cakes = Cake.objects.filter(bakery=OuterRef('bakery'), baked_at=baked_at)
```

Have you considered using the latest N number of cakes, or using a time range (the latest cakes baked in one hour)?

For your second question, are you sure you need to get all 10k records at once? If not, consider [using](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/pagination/) `Pagination` .

Comment: Would this necessitate using the second query set as a subquery in another filter call?

Comment: Pagination seems like what I was looking for ... I think what was happening is that my original query is extremely inefficient and as such the introduced latency wasn't due to the size of payload per se but the time it took for the Django query to process

Comment: What is your requirement for getting the "latest" cakes? If you use the latest N number of cakes or the latest cakes baked in T time you should be able to do it in one single query